# Wildcard in JS String replace method

Tags: javascript

replace("abc.example","example").replace("fg8uj.example","example").replace("okhzl.example","example").replace("58ki.example","example").

Is it possible to use a wild card instead of abc, fg8uj, okhzl, 58ki?
replace("*.example","example"). not works.

Comment: This is what regular expressions are for: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you provide a regular expression for the first argument, and use a wildcard in the regex:

```
str = str.replace(/\b[\w*?]*\.example/, "example);
```

That allows any number of "word characters" or `?` or `*` before the `.example` and requires a word boundary in front of it, but you'll want to tweak.

If you want to do it throughout the string (not just the first match), add the `g` flag to the regex.

More about regular expressions [here on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

[Here's](https://regex101.com/#javascript) a good place to play around with them.

Live example:

```js
var testValues = [
  "abc.example",
  "fg8uj.example",
  "okhzl.example",
  "58ki.example"
];
testValues.forEach(function(testValue) {
  var updatedValue = testValue.replace(/\b[\w?*]+\.example/, "example");
  snippet.log(testValue + " => " + updatedValue);
});
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```